# Create Task on multiple machines with logging

Tags: batch-file, logging, vbscript

I'm trying to create Tasks on multiple machines withing the domain and feed the scripts from a input file.

It could be either in VBS or BATCH, but I can't get it to work. 
This is what I have so far:

```
InputFile = "c:\scripts\input\workstations.Txt"
Const OverWriteFiles = True
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\scripts\output\log.log", 2)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
  On Error Resume Next
  oShell.run "cmd schtasks /Create /U lumcnet\user/p wachtwoord /SC DAILY /ST 05:02 /TN     ""Herstart"" /TR ""\""C:\PACS Beheer Tools\Werkstation herstarten\Notification.HTA\"" /F /RL HIGHEST /S" strComputer
  If Err Then myLog.WriteLine strComputer
  On Error Goto 0
Loop
myLog.Close

MsgBox "Done"
```

and:

```
FOR /f %%a IN (c:\scripts\input\workstation.txt) DO (
schtasks /Create /U lumcnet\pacs-report /p report /SC DAILY /ST 05:02 /TN "Herstart" /TR "\"C:\PACS Beheer Tools\Werkstation herstarten\Notification.HTA\"" /F /RL HIGHEST /S 2-%%a
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo %%a>>"c:\scripts\output\log.log"
) 
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Define "can't get it to work". Do you get an error? Is the task simply not created? Do you see access denied messages in the Security eventlog on the remote host? Also note that the `Run` method won't raise an error when the external command fails. You need to evaluate the return code instead (`rc = oShell.Run(...)`).

Comment: I get the following error; Line 9, Char 202, Error: Expected end of statement. This is probably because of quote ending after /S but the cmd should still take the computername from teh file (strComputer) placing strComputer withing quote's doesn't work either; Line 4, Char 5, Error: Object requierd: 'objFSO'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **You need to put a `\"` at the start and at the end of your command if your path has spaces**.....(Which you already had, and I took out - sorry about that:) )
2. You are also missing the `&` symbol between the cmd and the strComputer variable.
3. You have not defined objFSO.

Anyway, this seems to work over here for me:

```
InputFile = "c:\scripts\input\workstations.Txt"
Const OverWriteFiles = True
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\scripts\output\log.log", 2)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
  On Error Resume Next
  oShell.run "schtasks /Create /U lumcnet\user /p wachtwoord /SC DAILY /ST 05:00 /TN herstart /TR ""\""C:\admin folder\workstation reboot\Notification.HTA\"""" /F /RL HIGHEST /S " & strComputer
  If Err Then myLog.WriteLine strComputer
  On Error Goto 0
Loop
myLog.Close

MsgBox "Done"
```

**DISCLAIMER: I Would never recommend storing usernames and passwords like this. Anyone who has access to the underlying system could enumerate credentials.**

I hope that helps.

Comment: Except the logging, but Ansgar allready pointed me at the fact run methode won't raise and error if fails. So i have to figure out another way.

Comment: The `""\""` are required, otherwise the path (which contains spaces) wouldn't be between double quotes in the task, so the system wouldn't find the HTA. Also, you can simply run `oShell.Run "schtasks ..."`. Prepending a command with `cmd /c` is only required when you're using shell-builtins (e.g. redirection, pipes, or `mklink`).

Comment: Guess I cheered way to earlie, when I thought it worked (your first given string) it only created the task on the first pc in text file (and with no logging). The second string with "\" added does not make a task on any computer not even the first.

Comment: Hi... Have you tried cutting and pasting the whole script as it is now, also can you take out the on error resume next to see if you are actually getting some kind of error?

Comment: I copied the entire script as you placed it and I removed the line on error resume next, but no error.

Comment: ..Of course you cut and paste the code and updated the username and password right? anyway, I have revised the script slightly... Tested to work here... I hope it works for you ( I included your domain username and password). I would advise changing this now that it has been pasted up for the world to see..

Comment: I copied it, but ofcourse changed the user and password, I copied your latest edit and this seems to work. Many thanks for your time en effort! Up to challenge number 2, writing a log :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a spurious trailing `strComputer` in that line:

```
oShell.run "cmd ... /S" strComputer
```

Add a space after the `/S` and a concatenation operator between string and variable:

```
oShell.run "cmd ... /S " & strComputer
```

Comment: After adding the space after S and & before strComputer, it gives error; Line 4, Char 5, Error: Object requierd: 'objFSO'

Comment: That's because you haven't defined it dude! 
Add this line before line 4: 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). [see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198716.aspx ]

Comment: Excuses, i'm just not that great at VBS, i'm trying to understand though. I now managed to run the entire script without errors, but no new task has been created on the external computer. I tested the batch outside vbs just direct from an .bat and then it works so it's not like that is broken.

Comment: can you please provide the batch that you are using that works? or at least the intended cmd string without all the extra quoting? I'll see if I can create one that works for you.

Comment: Ofcourse, thank you, cmd string is between //here//! // schtasks /Create /U domain\user /p password /SC DAILY /ST 05:00 /TN reboot /TR "\"C:\admin folder\workstation reboot\Notification.HTA\"" /F /RL HIGHEST /S computer1 // computer1 is just one of the computers I want to use the vbs to read a text document with multiple computers

Comment: I have added an answer of my own since Mr. Grumpy wouldn't accept my edit to his answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Damien I didn't even see your edit until I logged back in just now. Please take a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284) on Meta to understand how suggested edits are reviewed.

Comment: Sorry sir - I am new here.